# How to use cURL to save html files from array?

Tags: php, html, curl, save

I'm trying save some files using cURL. I have managed to achieve this for a single url, but when I'm creating an array to keep multiple url's in it, then it is not working. I'm not getting any errors either even after turning on error reporting. The files are simply not being saved. My code in given below. Any help is much appreciated.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$var = "http://www.example.com/trailer/";

$urls = array("1423/10_Things_I_Hate_About_You/","1470/10.5__Apocalypse/");

$ch = curl_init();

foreach ($urls as $i => $url) {

$conn[$i]=curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($conn[$i], CURLOPT_URL, $url .$var);
curl_setopt($conn[$i], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($conn[$i], CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

// grab URL and pass it to the browser
$out = curl_exec($conn[$i]);

// close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($conn[$i]);

$fp = fopen($url . "index.html", 'w');
fwrite($fp, $out);
fclose($fp);
}
```

Comment: your concatenation is backwards should be `$var.$url`

Comment: yes!! you caught a issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How does file_get_contents and file_put_contents work for you? You could combine the following into a single line.

```
<?php
    $homepage = file_get_contents( 'http://www.example.com/' );
    file_put_contents( '/my/filename.html', $homepage );
?>
```

Alternatively, I wrote a curl wrapper class. Here is some sample usage:

https://github.com/homer6/altumo/blob/master/source/php/Http/OutgoingHttpRequest.md

```
$http_response =  $client->sendAndGetResponseMessage( true );
```

is the operative line.

Comment: Thanks for you answer!!! i never thought of it so the answer will be

<?php

$var = "http://www.example.com/";

$urls = array("1997/12_Angry_Men/","2091/127_Hours/");

 foreach($urls as $url) {

    $homepage = file_get_contents($var . $url);
    file_put_contents( $url . "index.html", $homepage );
 
 
}
?>

Comment: hi can you please tell how can i get result when each foreach is done? cause the array has more than 10000 url so i wanted to know which one is done so far. The reason is many times due to break in operation it stops downloading so if i can know how much in the loop has completed.

Comment: I would log what you want to track (or both). You could read the urls from a "to-do list" where each line has a url. Then, as each completes successfully, it removes that line from the "to-do list" and adds it to the "completed" list (which is a separate text file).

Comment: You can add an error handler function to log the ones that failed as well in an "error log" (which is, again, just a text file with one url per line). Then, it could log that error and continue on. In the end, your "to-do list" will be empty, but the "completed" and "error" lists will have multiple entries. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php